# Tree data with composite key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an issue that I can not solve correct. I've prepared an example to illustrate it.

Let's keep count of troopers in starships. We have some number of troopers in each starship. Each trooper has a personal number that is unique within starship. And each trooper has a superior officer, who is also a trooper and has superior officer too, and so on. We have some other information about troopers, that doesn't matter, so we just add an "info" field.
So:

```
create table starship(
  id bigint primary key,
  name varchar(100)
)

create table trooper(
  personal_number int not null,
  starship bigint not null reference starship (id),
  info varchar(1000),
  commander int,
  primary key(personal_number, starship),
  foreign key(commander, starship) reference trooper(personal_number, starship)
)
```

We have two table. "Starship" with starship name and id, and "trooper" where we have trooper personal number, his starship nymber, info, and his commander personal number.
I need to do CRUD operations with this data, but I can not build a proper entities. The issue is about writing "commander" data.

I'm trying to do it this way.

Starship:

```
@Entity(name = "starship")
public class Starship (
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", unique = true)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  private String name;
)
```

Trooper:

```
@Entity(name = "trooper")
public class Trooper {

  @EmbeddedId
  private TrooperKey id;

  @Column(name = "info")
  private String info;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId(value = "type")
  @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "parent", referencedColumnName = "portal_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "type", referencedColumnName = "type")
  })
  @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
  private Trooper commander;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "commander", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
  private Set<Trooper> subitems = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Trooper key:

```
@Embeddable
public class TrooperKey implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "personal_number")
  private Long personalNumber;

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "starship")
  private Starship starship;

}
```

I'm trying to use `@MapsId`, because otherwise I need to mark this join as `insertable = false, updatable = false`. But it still doesn't save the commander number in `commander` field in database.

Comment: I guess you only need to put annotation of  @ManyToOne on the Trooper field.

Comment: If I remove @MapsId, I'll have to add insertable = false ((